# Auto-close modal window, or close on click

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a tooltip that appears which I want to either auto-close after 1500ms, or close immediately if the user clicks anywhere on the page.

I've tried the following:

```
$('#action-result').fadeIn('fast').delay(1500).fadeOut('fast');
$('body').click(function(){

    $('#action-result').fadeOut('fast');

});
```

But for whatever reason, the delay seems to take complete control and doesn't allow anything else to happen to that element until the delay is over.

---

### EDIT

Thanks to Ohgodwhy and ThiefMaster, the only think I needed to do to the click function was add a stop to it to clear out the .delay() that was triggered earlier.

```
$('body').click(function(){

    $('#action-result').stop().fadeOut('fast');

});
```

Comment: `$('body').click(function(){ window.clearTimeout(); $('#action-result').fadeOut('fast');
 });`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use delay, use setTimeout.

```
$('#action-result').fadeIn('fast', function(){
  //callback for after fadeIn completes
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
  }, 1500);  //1500 is our delay
});
```

Clear the timeout on click.

```
$('body').click(function(){
  window.clearTimeout(); //timer cleared, now let's fadeOut.
  $('#action-result').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Comment: You might want to explain the **why**. Since `fadeIn/Out` use the animation queue, `.delay()` whouldn't be a problem...

Comment: I tried this, and unfortunately it does not auto-close. I'm not sure why.

Comment: just use $('#action-link').stop(); to stop all fx queues, including delays(intervals), fades, animations, as thiefmaster pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The following should achieve the desired functionality:

```
var x = setTimeout(function () { $("#action-result").fadeOut("fast"); }, 1500);
$("body").click(function () {
    $("#action-result").fadeOut("fast");
    clearTimeout(x);
});
```